# PostgreSQL PostGIS: Spatial join but keep all features that don't intersect

Tags: postgis, postgresql, attribute-joins, spatial-join, pgadmin-4

Spatial joining a point table to a polygon table, creating a new output table. So far I can only get the output table to contain features that satisfy the spatial join. However, I want the output to contain ALL features, even the ones that don't intersect. I also want to choose which columns are pulled through into the final output (in the case below, 5 columns from 'topo' and only 1 from 'adb')

Here's my code as it stands at the moment:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.wolv_topobuild_uprns_all;
CREATE TABLE public.wolv_topobuild_uprns_all AS
SELECT
  topo.id,
  topo.geom,
  topo.ogc_fid,
  topo.theme,
  topo.class,
  adb.uprn
FROM
  public.wolv_adb_slim as adb,
  public.wolv_topobuild as topo
WHERE
  ST_WITHIN(adb.geom, topo.geom)
```

From my research it seems I want to mix this spatial join with a full outer join, but being able to specify the columns I want in the output table.

I want the resulting output table to contain all of the original polygons but with the chosen metadata from the points where they fall inside a polygon. There will be some points that lie outside of the polygons... we can ignore them from the final output.

Comment: @Cyril do I need to specify? It's a spatial join, so it uses the geom column to make the join. There is no common column between the two tables.

Comment: add OR NOT ST_WITHIN(adb.geom, topo.geom)

Comment: @Cyril thanks. Where would I add it? At the end in the WHERE section?

Comment: WHERE
  ST_WITHIN(adb.geom, topo.geom) OR NOT  ST_WITHIN(adb.geom, topo.geom)

Comment: @Cyril thanks but strangely that took a minute to run, and the output table has 10 million rows. Where the two tables I was working only had 3000 each.

Comment: This is a clear case where using JOIN is mandated, because then you can specify a LEFT OUTER JOIN to return rows in the FROM table which have no match.

Comment: it is difficult for me to determine whether you have received the correct answer, without the initial data, you need to analyze them...

Comment: @Vince I'll try joins against the original source table. If you could show me how to write it as an answer that'd be great!

Comment: It's still not clear what result you want.  Please [edit] the question to clarify if you want all points or all polygons.

Comment: @Cyril is it wrong to do a join on a condition and its opposite. It is the same as no condition at all, so the same as a cross product. The solution here is as @Vince pointed out, to choose the table that should always be included and to apply a `left outer join` using a spatial `ON` condition

Comment: JGH publish the answer Theo F awaits...

Comment: It is important for me Theo F to be able to correctly formulate the question...

Comment: Theo Frun the query..and don't forget to take the answer if it is correct...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To obtain all `topo` rows, whether they have an `adb` or not, use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  topo.id,
  topo.geom,
  topo.ogc_fid,
  topo.theme,
  topo.class,
  adb.uprn
FROM
  public.wolv_topobuild as topo
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  public.wolv_adb_slim as adb ON ST_WITHIN(adb.geom, topo.geom)
```

Conversely, obtain all `adb` rows, whether they have a `topo` or not, use:

```
SELECT
  topo.id,
  topo.geom,
  topo.ogc_fid,
  topo.theme,
  topo.class,
  adb.uprn
FROM
  public.wolv_adb_slim as adb
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  public.wolv_topobuild as topo ON ST_WITHIN(adb.geom, topo.geom)
```

Note that points *ON* a polygon boundary will not have a match, whereas a `ST_Intersects` could return two boundaries in that case.

Best practice is to *always* use `JOIN` to join.

Comment: thanks Vince, that first one works great for my cause (I just had to add the CREATE TABLE part before it). I now have a polygon table which contains adb 'uprn' numbers (the points) where they fall within the polygons. Where no pointsfall within, the polygon is still created in the output, just with a null value in the uprn column. Also where multiple points fall within a polygon, the polygon is duplicated for each point, with a unique uprn stored against it. Brill.